# UnsupportedOperationException ERROR in Java Arraylist

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, arraylist, netbeans-8

I have two forms, first is for the Login and second one is the Main Form with JTable on it, that can display data from the database. This the code I used for viewing and studentlist. I can't figure out how I got the "UnsupportedOperationExemption" Error. I am new in Java. I am using Apache Netbeans.

```
    ArrayList<Student> list; 
    myQuery mq = new myQuery();

    public MainForm(){
        initComponents();
        view(); 
    }


    void view(){

        list = mq.studentlist();
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)studTable.getModel();
        Object[] row = new Object[11];

        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            row[0]=list.get(i).getStudID();
            row[1]=list.get(i).getLRN();
            row[2]=list.get(i).getGrade();
            row[3]=list.get(i).getLName();
            row[4]=list.get(i).getFName();
            row[5]=list.get(i).getMName();
            row[6]=list.get(i).getGender();
            row[7]=list.get(i).getBday();
            row[8]=list.get(i).getAge();
            row[9]=list.get(i).getCNumber();
            row[10]=list.get(i).getAdviser();

          model.addRow(row);
        }

    }
}
```

//----------------ArrayList Here---------------------------

```
   ArrayList<Student> studentlist = new ArrayList<>();
   DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(); 
   PreparedStatement ps;
   ResultSet rs;
   String query; 
   Student stud;

    try{
        query = "SELECT * FROM students";
        ps = myConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

       while(rs.next()){
           stud = new Student(rs.getInt("idstudents"),
                    rs.getInt("LRN"),
                    rs.getString("Grade"),
                    rs.getString("LName"),
                    rs.getString("FNname"),
                    rs.getString("MName"),
                    rs.getString("Gender"),
                    rs.getString("Bday"),
                    rs.getInt("Age"),
                    rs.getInt("CNumber"),
                    rs.getString("Adviser"));
           studentlist.add(stud);
       }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //return false;
    }
    return studentlist;
}
```

Comment: The most important part is your method `studentlist()`, but while we can't see its body we can't help you.

Comment: Im sorry i forgot, but here, i edited and added the method.

Comment: [edit] your question and post the stack trace you are getting.

Comment: This warning i am getting

Comment: warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
Note: C:\Users\inten\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StudentInformationSystem\src\Classes\MainForm.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 warning

Comment: In your question, you wrote that you are getting a `UnsupportedOperationException`. In your last comment you posted a compiler warning. They are two different things. Also, you can [edit] your question and add more details - like a compiler warning.

Comment: Please post the stack trace, plus any of your code from lines referenced in the stack trace and indicate which lines in your source correspond to the line numbers from the stack trace. As it stands, we have no idea where the problem is coming from, or even kid the code you posted is even related to the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a pair of backticks (``) around "students" in your `query`. That declares the table in the query.

Comment: My answer comes from reviewing an old program that used the `connection` methods. Hopefully it helps!